# Electron/Javascript: Detect when window is un/maximized

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I am creating an electron application with a custom window bar in place of the default Windows one. I need to know when the window is maximized or un-maximized in order to change the icon on the window bar to reflect the window's state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`maximize` / `unmaximized` event is availble for browserwindow. https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#event-maximize

Answer (score 6):

you can use:

```
const { remote } = require("electron");
var win = remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
if(win.isFullScreen()) {
  // your code here
}
```

or :

```
const { remote } = require("electron");
var win = remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
if(win.isMaximized()) {
  // your code here
}
```